# "Cannot read property 'findDOMNode' of undefined" when using React-widgets

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React & React-router, 0.13.3, and React-widgets 3.1.0, all installed with bower; and brunch for build.

In a route, I'm creating a drop-down like:

```
render: function()
{
  var trylist = ['pink', 'red', 'blue', 'white' ];
  var DropdownList = ReactWidgets.DropdownList;

  return (<DropdownList defaultValue="red" data={trylist} /> )
}
```

When I click on the drop-down, it gives this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'findDOMNode' of undefined

The file is shown as react-widgets.js:2015. At this file/line:

```
      findDOMNode: function findDOMNode(component) {
    return _reactDom2['default'].findDOMNode(component);
```

Help very much appreciated! Am rather a noob with JS, React.

Answer (score 1):

The version of React-widgets you are using requires React 0.14 and also React-Dom 0.14

You need to upgrade to `React 0.14.3` and also install React-Dom.

This is for npm.  Sorry I don't know the equivalent in bower...

```
npm update react
npm install react-dom
```

Comment: Thanks very much; will try.